# Send php response to ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, return

Okay I have a php script which ends as so :

```
if ($success)
{
    $result = array('success' => true);
}
else
{
    $result = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Something happened');
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
}
  echo json_encode($result);
```

And some jquery that I was planning on having alert me when my script is working.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: './contactengine.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(response) {
                        alert("GOOD");
                },
                error: function() {
                        alert("BAD");
                }
    });

});
```

edited source

Comment: Is your `return 1` statement called within a function?

Comment: You should output the 1 as a JSON.

Comment: @RPM. You write code with two tilde= \`code\`

Comment: @RPM. You meant `Thanks for the heads up` ... **:)**

Answer (score 8):

```
        <?php 
        if ($success){
             $result = array("status" => "1");

             echo json_encode($result);
            }
            else{
              print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=/404.html\">";
            }    
        ?>
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {

          $.ajax({
                           type: 'GET',
                           url:  'Thatscriptsomething.php',
                           cache: 'false',
                           dataType: 'json',
                           success: function(response) {
                               if(response.status == "1") {
                                    alert("we having a working script");
                               } else {
                                    alert("Oops, script is a no go");
                               }
                            }
                        });
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: Back working on this and I get forwarded to a page which says: 
`{"success":true}`

it goes to a page domain.com/script.php when it shouldn't go there.

Comment: I tried to run your script and it doesn't work. If I do alert(response) I got the {"status":1}<script> javascript here </script>... So I guess that's the reason it doesn't work. Also, if I don't remove dataType: 'json' script does nothing.

Answer (score 5):

Basic example - it works for me

**PHP RESPONSE**

```
$value =  array('msg' => 'true' );
          echo json_encode($value);
```

**AJAX METHOD**

```
 $.ajax({  
  type: 'post',  
  url: 'URL',  
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  dataType:'JSON',
  data: formData,
      success: function(value) {
                if (value.msg ==  'true') {
                      //your action
                }else{
                      //your action
                }
      }
});
```