# Get selected value from dynamic dropdown in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a button that adds a row to a table so that data can be inserted. One of the `<td>` tags populates a dropdown menu. I need to get the value from that dropdown to post in an ajax call back to a php page to insert the data in the database. Everything I've tried has returned undefined for `position_ID`.

I'm getting a 500 Error on the POST and I think it's due to `var position_ID = $(this).parents('tr').find('.positionList').val();`, in the Insert function, not being set.

HTML Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <script src='jquery-3.4.1.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
      <script src='script.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" name="add" id="add">Add</button>
        <table id="dataTable">
            <tr>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Location Number</th>
                <th>Position</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?PHP>
    $sql = "SELECT positionID, name FROM position";

    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

    $position_arr = array();

    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
        $positionID = $row['positionID'];
        $name = $row['name'];

        $position_arr[] = array("positionID" => $positionID, "name" => $name);
    }

    // encoding array to json format

    $JSON_array = json_encode($position_arr);
    echo $JSON_array;
?>
<?PHP>
    if(isset($_POST["last_name"], $_POST["first_name"], $_POST["location_num"], $_POST["position_ID"]))
    {
         $lastName = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["last_name"]);
         $firstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["first_name"]);      
         $locationNum = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["location_num"]);
         $positionID = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["position_ID"]);

         $sqlInsertEmployee = "INSERT INTO employee(lastName, firstName, positionID, locationID) SELECT ?, ?, positionID, locationID from location join position p on p.positionID = ? where number = ?";
         $stmtInsertEmployee = mysqli_prepare($db,$sqlInsertEmployee);
         mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmtInsertEmployee, "ssss", $lastName,$firstName,$positionID,$locationNum,);
         mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtInsertEmployee);
         mysqli_stmt_close($stmtInsertEmployee);
    }   
?>
```

Script code:

```
$('#add').click(function(){
       var html = '<tr>';
       html += '<td contenteditable id="lastName"></td>';
       html += '<td contenteditable id="firstName"></td>';
       html += '<td contenteditable id="locationNum"></td>';
       html += '<td contenteditable id="positionID"><select class="positionList"><option></option></select>';   

       $(document).ready(function() {
              var data
              $.ajax({
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'get-position.php',
                data: data,
                success: function(data) {
                    // begin accessing JSON data here
                  console.log(data)
                  //data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                  var html_to_append = '';
                  html_to_append += '<option value="0">-- Select One --</option>'
                  $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    html_to_append += '<option value="' + item.positionID + '">' + item.name + '</option>';
                  });
                  $(".positionList").html(html_to_append);
                },
              })
            })


       html += '</td><td><button type="button" name="insert" id="insert">Insert</button></td>';
       html += '</tr>';
       $('#dataTable tr:first').after(html);
    });




    $(document).on('click', '#insert', function(){
       var last_name = $('#lastName').text();
       var first_name = $('#firstName').text();    
       var location_num = $('#locationNum').text();

       var position_ID = $(this).parents('tr').find('.positionList').val();

       console.log(position_ID);

       if(first_name != '' && last_name != '' && location_num != '')
       {
        $.ajax({
         url:"insert.php",
         method:"POST",
         data:{last_name:last_name, first_name:first_name, location_num:location_num, position_ID:position_ID},
         success:function(data)
         {
          $('#alert_message').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
          $('#dataTable').DataTable().destroy();
          fetch_data();

         }
        });
        setInterval(function(){
         $('#alert_message').html('');
        }, 5000);
       }
       else
       {
        alert("All Fields is required");
       }
     });
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you better.

Comment: Your selectbox has a ID and every time you add a row the ID get added again with the row, and as you the ID should be unique.

Comment: @k3llydev I have added more detail now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [.val() method](https://api.jquery.com/val/) is used to get the value of an element.

Also note that @Kaka Sarmah is correct. Even this will not work because you're creating multiple elements with the same ID. IDs must be unique. Try giving it a class instead.

```
html += '<td contenteditable class="positionID"><select class="positionList"><option></option></select>';
```

Then in your javascript you can try to locate it using that class. Something like:

```
var position_ID = $(this).parents('tr').find('.positionList').val();
```

Comment: How can see the value of `position_ID`? I tried a `console.log(position_ID)` but it doesn't display anything. All I see in console is a 500 error on the POST.

Comment: Nevermind...I got it using the debugger. The value of `position_ID` is getting set. Looks like maybe an issue with the AJAX call. Any thoughts?

Comment: if you're getting a 500 error on the post request that means your server is responding with "Internal Server Error". The issue isn't the request, its that its not getting anything from the server.

Comment: Should the php send a response?

Comment: Yeah if you're trying to get data from the server to the client. It looks like you're trying to dual purpose your php script. Break the tasks into 2 separate scripts. One for getting the data, and one for posting data back to the server.

Comment: I actually have them split into two files. I didn't show that here. I added `$value =  array('msg' => 'true' ); echo json_encode($value)` to the end of the PHP insert code and modified the success function to check if `msg == 'true'`. It doesn't appear the the PHP is producing a response. I did it like it's shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114852/send-php-response-to-ajax/10114935#10114935

Comment: Do you see any response if you visit get-position.php directly in the browser, or still a 500 error?

Comment: I get this page is currently unable to handle this request. What kind of response would I get from a script that only inserts data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41062714/currently-unable-to-handle-this-request-http-error-500

Comment: Thank you for the troubleshooting tips. Turns out there was a rouge comma in the insert php.

Comment: Ah I see. Does the javascript change help fix the issue with the row?

Comment: Sweet. Good deal.