# Get id for input text value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a autocomplete field where I need to get the database id of the displayed text to send to jQuery to update database. I don't know how to get the id of the select text.

This function gets the available values as you type, then when the text is selected it displays the text.

```
$(function() {
            $(".positionList").autocomplete({
                source: "get-position.php?",
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $(".positionList").val(ui.item.value);
                }
            });
        });
```

This is where the input text box is:

```
<tr>
<td> <div contentEditable='true' class='edit' id='postionID_<?php echo $id; ?>'><input type='text' class='positionList' value='<?php echo $position; ?>' /></div></td>
```

When I get here I have the `$id` of the user to update, `$position` which is the name, and `$positionID` which is what needs to be sent to the jQuery.

This does the update and `var value` is empty. This variable should contain the `$positionID`.

```
$(".edit").focusout(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("editMode");

        var id = this.id;
        var split_id = id.split("_");
        var field_name = split_id[0];
        var edit_id = split_id[1];

        var value = $(this).text();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'update.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: { field:field_name, value:value, id:edit_id },
            //data: { field:field_name, value:value, id:edit_id, checked:checkedStatus },
            success:function(response){               
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: You've done this before... remember: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57795319/get-selected-value-from-dynamic-dropdown-in-table

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is you are asking for the innerHTML of the input element:

```
<input type='text' class='positionList' value='<?php echo $position; ?>' />
```

The issue is the input tag is a self closing tag. This means that it is exactly the same as this:

```
<input type='text' class='positionList' value='<?php echo $position; ?>'></input>
```

This means that there is no "innerHTML" as we left it blank

So to fix this we can just change your Javascript line from:

```
var value = $(this).text();
```

To this:

```
var value = $(this).val();
```

This retrieves the "value" attribute of the input field rather than the innerHTML.

Comment: that makes a lot sense but `$position` is a string and I need to provide the `$positionID` to `var value`. How does that fit in here?

Comment: As in your comment on the post, I was able to `var position_ID = $(this).parents('tr').find('.positionList').val();` to the javascript to get the value. I didn't make the connection to this question and the previous post initially.

Comment: Cool! Glad you sorted it out. Remember the .text() and .val() does not refer to the content type you are trying to retrieve but rather the method in which it is retrieved. 